# Практические различия между простой функцией "func(obj, param)" и методом объекта "obj.func(param)"

Tags: javascript

Допустим есть некая функция `func` которая выполняет действие над объектом `obj`, (DOM узлом) например присоединяет к нему потомка.

Изначально я решил задачу через stand-alone функцию вида `func(obj, param)` но потом решил, что удобнее будет, если сделать это в виде метода объекта и "прицеплять" ее `как obj.func(param)`, однако как я понял, объявить функцию как метод заранее, чтобы потом ее "цеплять" к любому объекту к которому захочется нельзя, нужно заранее присоединять метод к объекту, если хочешь им воспользоваться:

```
obj: {
func = function(param)  { ... }
}
```

Зачем тогда нужны методы объекта? Выглядит как лишние строчки кода и лишнее место в памяти.

Comment: про прототипы слышали?

Answer (score 0):

К примеру есть объект User:

```
let user = {
name : "Ivan",
surname : "Ivanovich",
getFullName :  function() {
  return `${this.name} ${this.surname}`;
 }
};

console.log(user.getFullName());
```

Консоль: Ivan Ivanovich.
Вот один из примеров методов объекта, также методы очень полезны при работе с классами, и наследованиями.

Answer (score 0):

Необязательно сразу цеплять функцию и так никто не делает, все цепляют если цепляют через прототип

```
Class.prototype.methodName = function () {}
```

тогда функция не дублируется внутри объектов созданных через этот класс. И ее необязательно сразу "цеплять" , можно в любой момент написать..

**Различия усложняет много кода для простых задач и наоборот упрощает для сложных приложений!!!!!!!!**

Answer (score 0):

Простая функция, принимающая всё необходимое чрез аргументы, более универсальна, так как теоретически у неё нет состояния, которое бы хранилось между вызовами (хотя некоторые умудряются его всё-таки создать). Метод объекта подразумевает некое состояние, которое существует вместе с объектом.

Хотя отсутствие такого состояния это клёво, но довольно часто менее удобно. ООП интуитивно понятно, и то что, например, объект `Собака` может `гавкать` кажется более естественным чем возможность `гавкать` с помощью `Собаки`.

Ну а чтобы прицепить метод к объекту есть много способов (хорошие статьи о ООП в js есть на [learn.javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru)). Мне нравится такой:

```
var Dog = function(name, voice) { // почти класс :-)

    this.name = name; // публичное свойство

    var _realName = name; // приватное свойство

    this.bark = function() { // публичный метод
        var name;
        if (this.name !== _realName) {
            name = this.name + ' (на самом деле ' + _realName + ')';
        } else {
            name = this.name;
        }

        return name + ': ' + _bark(voice);
    }

    function _bark(voice) { // приватный метод
        return voice + '-' + voice;
    }

};

var dog = new Dog('Шарик', 'гав');
alert(dog.bark());
dog.name = 'Лошарик';
alert(dog.bark());
```